# absolute positioning inside display:table-cell

Tags: html, css

In IE11, the second image does not correctly center **vertically** and instead sits at the top of the div.

```css
#sliderContainer #mask {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}

#sliderContainer content {
  position: relative;
  display: table;
  height: auto;
  width: 200%;
}

#sliderContainer content>div {
  display: table-cell;
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
  height: auto;
  vertical-align: top;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  background-color: #54314e;
}

#sliderContainer content>div:last-child {
  background-color: #9F4585;
}

.vertical-float {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div id="sliderContainer" *ngIf="activeCircle > 0">
  <div id="mask">
    <content>
      <div>
        <div class="col-xs-4">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150/ffffff/000000" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <!--
        -->
      <div>
        <div class="vertical-float">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/350x50/ffffff/000000" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </content>
  </div>
</div>
```

Why is this the case? It is as if it doesn't know how to calculate the top position relative to the height of its containing div.

Answer (score 0):

So very oddly, this is resolved by removing the relative positioning of the containing div element. In this case it was on `#sliderContainer content > div`.

```css
#sliderContainer #mask {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}

#sliderContainer content {
  position: relative;
  display: table;
  height: auto;
  width: 200%;
}

#sliderContainer content>div {
  display: table-cell;
  /*position: relative;*/
  width: 50%;
  height: auto;
  vertical-align: top;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  background-color: #54314e;
}

#sliderContainer content>div:last-child {
  background-color: #9F4585;
}

.vertical-float {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div id="sliderContainer" *ngIf="activeCircle > 0">
  <div id="mask">
    <content>
      <div>
        <div class="col-xs-4">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150/ffffff/000000" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <!--
        -->
      <div>
        <div class="vertical-float">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/350x50/ffffff/000000" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </content>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Second img is not centering because you have used "vertical-float" for image. The "vertical-float" div is position absolute. So to center this "vertical-float" div, write the css :

```
.vertical-float {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -175px;
    margin-top:-25px;
}
```

margin-left : (div width)/2 px;
margin-top : (div height)/2 px;

Comment: I have clarified the question. I only want to center it vertically.

Comment: I think that "translateY" is not working in IE11. I have edited in my post.

Comment: `translateY` is supported by IE11. http://caniuse.com/#search=translateY